# R ggplot2: Unable to get the right labels on Y-axis when using stacked barplot while trying to use percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

this is how my data is:

As you can see each ID has 10 observations with a certain "status" at each time point between 0-10 for each ID.

```
       id    year status
1        20    0      2
2        20    1      2
3        20    2      2
4        20    3      5
5        20    4      5
6        20    5      5
7        20    6      5
8        20    7      5
9        20    8      5
10       20    9      5
11       20   10      5
12       35    0      2
13       35    1      5
14       35    2      5
15       35    3      5
16       35    4      5
17       35    5      5
18       35    6      5
19       35    7      5
20       35    8      5
```

So, this was how my initial plot command was

```
axs=dat %>% group_by(year)%>% ggplot(aes(x=year,fill = factor(status))) +
+   geom_bar(position = "stack", width = 1) + stat_count()+
+   scale_fill_hue(labels = c("Not listed", "Listed", "Removed", "Given", "Wasted")) +
+   labs(title= "Trajectory ",x = "time", y = "Percent ", fill = "Status") + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,1))
```

Then I wanted to convert the Y-axis into percentage plot, so my command was changed to:

```
axs + scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x){round(x*100/length(unique(dat$id)))})
```

So then I modified it as:

```
axs + scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x){round(x*100/length(unique(dat$id)))}, breaks=c(0,100,25))
```

The same figure is what I get when I type break= seq(0,100,25)).
When I use the breaks in the scale_y_continuous command, I get only 0 on the Y-axis. If I dont use it, then I am getting 101 in the Y-axis, which I am trying to eliminate (because its percentage on the X-axis).

Can someone tell me how I can sort out this problem?
Would greatly appreciate it,
Thanks,
Shalom

Comment: I am sorry, The initial part of my post was erased out for some reason.Also, apparently you may have to click the imgur links to see the graphs. Sorry, I am really a novice at posting the images.   Cheers.

Comment: Could you try this and see if works for your issue? `dat %>% group_by(year,status) %>% summarise(N=n()) %>%
  left_join(dat %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(Total=n())) %>%
  mutate(Percent=N/Total) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(year),fill = factor(status)))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill", width = 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  scale_fill_hue(labels = c("Not listed", "Listed", "Removed", "Transplanted", "Died")) +
  labs(title= "Trajectory in less than 65 yrs age",x = "Years after graft failure", y = "Percent of patients", fill = "Status")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
axs=dat %>% group_by(year)%>% ggplot(aes(x=year,fill = factor(status))) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", width = 1) + stat_count()+
  scale_fill_hue(labels = c("Not listed", "Listed", "Removed", "Transplanted", "Died")) +
  labs(title= "Trajectory in less than 65 yrs age",x = "Years after graft failure", y = "Percent of patients", fill = "Status") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(100*x/max(x),'%'))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,10,1))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks so much. This gave me a couple of sleepless nights.:-)))) Any idea, why I was getting that issue? Would greatly appreciate some light on what i was doign wrong.

Comment: The first graph came out OK, the subsequent graphs are giving breaks at 66.7 and 33.3%. Also it is giving 10 numbers after the decimal. I tried "round" to no avail. Also using breaks=seq(0,100,25) is also useless. Any way to change the breaks in Y-axis. Thanks again.

Comment: @Shalom Try using `labels = function(x) paste0(100*round(x/max(x),0),'%')`

Comment: Now the Y-axis breaks are 4, but the values are labeled 0,0, 100, 100.

Comment: I suspect it is an issue with the axis labels. First try plotting without labels and see how the values are distributed and what is the max. After checking that try playing with the function in the labels replacing the `max(x)` by the value you got from the original axis!

Comment: Same issue. No resolution of that problem :-((

Comment: @Shalom Let me think about how to solve you issue. It looks like a data issue that is not adjusting to scale!

Comment: I figured it out. I made a proportion of each of the status for each yr and converted them into a percentage form and then did a stacked barplot. Way simpler. I dont know why I didnt do it earlier. Made it so much easier.

Comment: @Shalom Great job!